# Border-box CSS not working properly

Tags: css, border, sizing

I have the following code: http://www.designated.net.au/testbed/test/

```
 body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #000000;
 }

 #page {
    margin:0% 10% 0% 10%;
    width:80%;
    height:1000px;
    border:solid #333333;
    border: 0 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;
 }
```

As far as I know that should give me an inner border on the left and right of 10px, but instead I get a border inside the whole thing of about 2px.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed for me in Chrome, Safari, IE 7/8/9: http://jsfiddle.net/XsNck/

I believe your border declaration syntax was incorrect.

**Not Working**

```
border:solid #333333;
border: 0 10px;
```

**Working**

```
border-style: solid;
border-color: #333;
border-width: 0 10px;
```

From the spec:

> The ‘border’ property is a shorthand property for setting the same
>   width, color, and style for all four borders of a box. Unlike the
>   shorthand ‘margin’ and ‘padding’ properties, the ‘border’ property
>   cannot set different values on the four borders. To do so, one or more
>   of the other border properties must be used.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-style

Incidentally (in light of the question title), this isn't directly related to the `box-sizing` property; `box-sizing` controls how the dimensions of a box are calculated (specifically, whether or not to include padding and borders). It doesn't change the border size.

Comment: Works for me as well in Firefox 17 (Aurora, 17a2).

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Firefox.  Both the old code and the new code work in that applet of yours.

Comment: Your page looks like it is missing `border-width: 0 10px;` in your CSS file (you have `border: 0 10px;` instead)

Comment: Follow-on question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328340/how-can-i-give-this-css-an-inner-border